# XSLT - Page break should happen when particular xml tag matches the template

Tags: xml, xslt

Consider the below XML File I want to write xslt for Each `<info`> tag details should start in new page

```
<catalog>
<cd>
    <title>1999 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>2000 Grammy Nominees</title>
    <artist>Many</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
</cd>
<info>
    <company>Grammy</company>
    <price>10.20</price>
    <year>1999</year>
</info>
<cd>
    <title>For the good times</title>
    <artist>yyy</artist>
    <country>UK</country>
</cd>
<cd>
    <title>Big Willie style</title>
    <artist>vvh</artist>
    <country>USA</country>
</cd>
<info>
    <company>Columbia</company>
    <price>9.90</price>
    <year>1997</year>
</info>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="catalog/info">
       <fo:block break-before="page">         
       </fo:block> 
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

When the xml tag `<info>` matches the template `<xsl:template match="catalog/info">` it should start on new page..
I'm not sure which attribute can be use for it..
How to use page break in xslt?
Thanks!!

Comment: you are using the wrong slash. Try `<xsl:template match="catalog/info">`

Comment: Do you know what the resulting XSL-FO should look like? If yes, please add it to your question. If not, then your question is not about XSLT.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I'm using XSLT to transform XML into the XSL-FO.. I don't know how to write xslt and how the fo will convert for new page break scenario.

Comment: If you don't know what XSL-FO you want as the result of the transformation, then find out before you ask about how to write the XSLT that will do the transformation.

Comment: The gory details are in https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/, a more digestible source for someone wanting to learn XSL-FO would be https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/pfux/index.htm